# 403 - CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django

Hello I hava a problem with Django, I have a this error:

CSRF token missing or incorrect.

and my code is:

```
 <h1>Registro de llamadas</h1>


    <form action="{% url 'registro:guardar' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Duracion: <input type="text" name="duracion"  /> </br>
    Tipo de llamada: 
    <select name="tipo" form="carform">
      <option value="1">Local</option>
      <option value="2">Nacional</option>
      <option value="3">Internacional</option>
    </select>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Grabar" />
</form>

{% if llamadas %}
    <ul>
    {% for ll in llamadas %}
        <li><a href="a">{{ ll.duracion }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No tenemos ninguna llamada</p>
{% endif %}
```

and views.py I have:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('registro/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))


def guardar(request):
    template = loader.get_template('registro/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

Please some help, I searched other question but not solve my problem.

THanks!

Comment: Have you got `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` in your middleware settings?

Comment: yes I have CsrfViewMiddleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your view.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render

@csrf_exempt
def guardar(request,username=None, errmsg=None):
    template = 'registro/index.html'
    ctx = {}
    render(request, template, ctx)
```

Comment: no, nothing change

Comment: I edited the view, try do it again

Comment: Please don't recommend `render_to_response`, it has been obsoleted by `render` for years.

Comment: thanks I don't knew it

Comment: The `render` shortcut takes the template name (e.g. 'registro/index.html').

Answer (score 2):

For the CSRF token to work properly you need to include a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) when you use your template.

To avoid the extra boilerplate this involves django comes with a shortcut function which adds this for you automatically when rendering a template. This is [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render).

To use this change your view to be.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def guardar(request):
    return render(request, 'registro/index.html', {})
```

For more information [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it) of the Django docs is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `request` is the *second* argument to the [`template.render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) method, but you are passing it as the first.

You can fix your views as follows:

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('registro/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))

def guardar(request):
    template = loader.get_template('registro/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))
```

As Simon suggests in his answer, it is easier to use the `render` shortcut instead of manually loading and rendering the template.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'registro/index.html', {})

def guardar(request):
    return render(request, 'registro/index.html', {})
```